# Linear decay as learning rate scheduler (pytorch)

Tags: pytorch

I have read about [LinearLR](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LinearLR.html) and ConstantLR in the Pytorch docs but I can't figure out, how to get a linear decay of my learning rate. Say I have `epochs = 10` and `lr=0.1` then I want to linearly reduce my learning-rate from `0.1` to `0` (or any other number) in 10 steps i.e by `0.01` in each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two constraints you have are: `lr(step=0)=0.1` and `lr(step=10)=0`. So naturally, `lr(step) = -0.1*step/10 + 0.1 = 0.1*(1 - step/10)`.

This is known as the polynomial learning rate scheduler. Its general form is:

```
def polynomial(base_lr, iter, max_iter, power):
    return base_lr * ((1 - float(iter) / max_iter) ** power)
```

Which in your case would be called with `polynomial(base_lr=0.1, max_iter=10, power=1)`.